# Get property from {} object

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using library which has a method `loadUserInfo(): KeycloakPromise<{}, void>` . I'm calling it using `this.getKeycloakInstance().loadUserInfo().success(data => {
            this.user.id = (data).sub;

I checked using debugger that this `data` object has field sub which I want to assign to `this.user.id` I cannot do so becasue I'm getting compilation error: `TS2339: Property 'sub' does not exist on type '{}'.`

I cannot change return type of method loadUserInfo() as it's external lib which I have to use. Can I get this `sub` property somehow without error?

Answer (score 3):

You can with `variable['sub']`, or by typing your variable as `any`.

```
this.getKeycloakInstance()
  .loadUserInfo()
  .success(data => this.user.id = data.sub); // error

this.getKeycloakInstance()
  .loadUserInfo()
  .success(data => this.user.id = data['sub']); // no error

this.getKeycloakInstance()
  .loadUserInfo()
  .success(data => this.user.id = (data as any).sub); // no error

this.getKeycloakInstance()
  .loadUserInfo()
  .success((data: any) => this.user.id = data.sub); // no error
```

Comment: chose 4th option - seems the most elegant to me.

Comment: That's why I put all of them in the first place ;)